# How do I completely fill a <table> 100% with <tbody> in HTML?

Tags: html, css, browser

I have some HTML that inject with Javascript into a web page. The final HTML I inject looks like:

```
<table style="border-width: 0px; margin 0px; width:100%; height: 100%; padding:0px;">
    <tbody style="border-width: 0px; margin 0px; width:100%; height: 100%; padding:0px;">
```

For some odd reason when I examine tbody in Firebug, its size seems to be 4px smaller than the table. How do I get the  to fill up ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

try adding the following css to your table:

```
border-collapse: collapse;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Yes this fixed it! I wonder why though even though i specified border-width to be 0 it didn't have same effect.

Answer (score 28):

Try adding:

```
border-collapse: collapse;
```

To your `table`. Or try setting:

```
display: block;
```

or

```
display: table
```

on the `tbody` element.

Comment: This would probably be better as a comment or actually provide an answer and then some extra comments?

Comment: display: table and width:100% on tbody worked for me